# How to get serial number through NSDMananger?

Tags: android

I am working on Android NSD to discovering hardware devices with help of service type and also getting that device ipaddress. My requirement is to get Serial number of hardware device. Please share your thoughts. below is the code for NSD implementation.

```
 @Override
            public void onDiscoveryStopped(String serviceType) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Discovery stopped: " + serviceType);        
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
                mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
                mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
            }
        };
    }

    public void initializeResolveListener() {
        mResolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener() {

            @Override
            public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Resolve failed" + errorCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Resolve Succeeded. " + serviceInfo);

                if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "IP address ::"serviceInfo.getHost().getHostAddress());
                    return;
                }
                mService = serviceInfo;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: did u tried with TelephonyManager?

Comment: i did't tried but I need connected hardware device serial number, its not Android related device. Its a hardware device which is connected to network with wired internet cable.

Comment: ohh , so where r u executing above code? in android device right?

Comment: yes, In android device only.

Comment: ok then u try there with telephon..manager right?